# Quotient of liminf

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ with $b_n>0$ for any $n$. Does this hold?

$$\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}= \frac{\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n}{\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n}$$

Comment: If $a_n\to -\infty$ and $b_n\to \infty$, the right hand side is not defined (e.g. $a_n=-n, b_n=n$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  The inequality that we do have (provided all values are finite and all denominators are non-zero, and provided $a_n > 0$) is
$$
\frac{\liminf a_n}{\limsup b_n} \leq
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq 
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq 
\frac{\limsup a_n}{\liminf b_n}
$$
For an example of equality of the outer bounds, consider the sequences $a_n = \{2,4,2,4,\dots\}$ and $b_n = \{1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,\dots\}$.

For an example of strict inequality of the outer bounds, consider the sequences $a_n = \{2,4,2,4,\dots\}$ and $b_n = \{1,3,1,3,\dots\}$